# Report fomula causes runtime error

Tags: crystal-reports

When I check my formula from Crystal Reports, it finds no errors. But when I run my project I get a runtime error. How can I resolve this?

```
NumberVar t := 0;

IF 
(
    ToNumber({3ColTrailBalSumm.DR_BEFORE}) - (ToNumber({3ColTrailBalSumm.CR_BEFORE}) -
    ToNumber({3ColTrailBalSumm.CR_BETWEEN}) + ToNumber({3ColTrailBalSumm.DR_BETWEEN})) > 0
)
THEN
(
    WhilePrintingRecords;
    t := ToNumber({3ColTrailBalSumm.DR_BEFORE}) - ToNumber({3ColTrailBalSumm.CR_BEFORE}) - 
    ToNumber({3ColTrailBalSumm.CR_BETWEEN}) + ToNumber({3ColTrailBalSumm.DR_BETWEEN});
)
ELSE
(
    t := 0;
)
```

[image]

Comment: What is the name of your formula field?

Comment: after_cr  and after_dr.Have two formulas . Other one same as i mentioned above.

Comment: when I remove WhilePrintingRecords; report generate successfully.but calculation is wrong.

Comment: have you tried declaring the variable with LOCAL?

Comment: Use WhilePrintingRecord right at the start above Numbervar declaration.